# Maximizing windows underneath my form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, screen, toolbar, maximize

I have a toolbar that is always on the top (topmost = true) but when i maximize other programs the top of their windows is hidden behind it. I want them to maximize BENEATH my toolbar so i can close/minimize them etc... Like an upside down taskbar, literally changing the screen working area...

Is this possible? I have seen it done in "Cairo Shell"

Comment: Do you mean you want a window that "docks" to the side of the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you achive by use TopMost property of Form. Instead you may need to use [SetWindowPos](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowPos)() WIN32 API call

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);
static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, had to lookup the vb etc, but got what I needed. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reserve an area on the desktop for your program and make all other programs not use that area when maximized, then you have to register your app to Window's appbar list with the API **SHAppBarMessage**

I havent found any good code to do this in .Net but if you google it maybe you'll be lucky.

Here are one:
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1202570&page=1